# NetBeans IDE 8.1 HTML Class background highlighted?

Tags: html, class, netbeans, ide

NetBeans IDE 8.1 HTML undefined class background highlighted with light green color, I want to get ride of this background?

[image: Here you can see this in image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try this: Tools->Editor->Highlighting and turn off the "Mark Occurrences of Symbol Under Caret". I don't know if your issue is quite the same as this but it's worth a go.

Comment: Still have problem.

Comment: Late response? Did it work for a bit and then stop working or have you only just tried it?

Comment: It didn't work for a bit too, these setting didn't effect anything. Also I had restarted netBeans and PC too.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure then, I've voted up your question hopefully someone will sort it out for you.

Comment: Same here —it is driving me mad… Voted up the question.

Comment: @Cutter — I tried your solution, and it works after restarting the IDE. But after a short time, it is back to the old trick as soon as I click in a file pane. Any clue?